# C Preprocessor testing definedness of multiple macros

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, logical-operators, preprocessor-directive

I searched the site but did not find the answer I was looking for so here is a really quick question.

I am trying to do something like that :

```
#ifdef _WIN32 || _WIN64
     #include <conio.h>
#endif
```

How can I do such a thing? I know that _WIN32 is defined for both 32 and 64 bit windows so I would be okay with either for windows detection. I am more interested in whether I can use logical operators like that with preprocessor directives, and if yes how, since the above does not work.

Compiling with gcc I get :

> warning: extra tokens at end of #ifdef directive , and it basically just takes the first MACRO and ignores the rest.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
// do stuff
#endif
```

The [defined](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/cpp.html#SEC38a_) macro tests whether or not a name is defined and lets you apply logical operators to the result.

Answer (score 7):

You must use `#if` and special operator [`defined`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html#Defined)

Answer (score 4):

I think it should be possible this way:

```
#if defined block1 || defined block2 /*or any other boolean operator*/
   /*Code*/
#endif
```

More information [here](http://books.google.com.ar/books?id=Nfh5-L3NBTQC&pg=PA536&lpg=PA536&dq=preprocessor+directive+c+logical&source=bl&ots=Ny400rakrd&sig=-bf45YoobTJiiVGoBhtBpA7G82M&hl=es&ei=zzktSqynIt7flQe69O3pCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2#PPA536,M1)

Answer (score 1):

Use defined:

```
#if defined(A) || defined(B)
    #include <whatever.h>
#endif
```