# Boolean in ifdef: is "#ifdef A && B" the same as "#if defined(A) && defined(B)"?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

In C++, is this:

```
#ifdef A && B
```

the same as:

```
#if defined(A) && defined(B)
```

?

I was thinking it wasn't, but I haven't been able to find a difference with my compiler (VS2005).

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965700/c-preprocessor-testing-definedness-of-multiple-macros I see that they are C and C++, but the preprocessors are basically the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085533/is-a-c-preprocessor-identical-to-a-c-preprocessor

Comment: Will someone quote and interpret the standard to decide if it is legal or not (it should not work for sure, but should it compile)? I'm unable to after 15 minutes of reading chap "16 Preprocessing directives".

Answer (score 103, accepted):

They are not the same. The first one doesn't work (I tested in gcc 4.4.1). Error message was:

> test.cc:1:15: warning: extra tokens at
>   end of #ifdef directive

If you want to check if multiple things are defined, use the second one.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I'm using Microsoft's compiler and it seems to allow it, but it just didn't seem right to me.

Comment: You cannot prove things using some single compiler. Refer to the standard, which states that this is invalid.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit However, some compilers extend the standard. Saying "it works in a certain compiler" isn't an attempt to prove it's valid; it's noting that a certain compiler extends the standard in a certain way.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: Agreed, but this answer does not do that. It responds to a question that begins "in C++...." with what appears to be a general fact about C++. At first glance, Evan tested his theory with one compiler then assumed it's true for all, by way of a guarantee from the language itself. If he determined that this behaviour is a GCC extension and said "this is a GCC extension" (with link to reference material) then that would be okay! (albeit not really an answer to this particular question)

Comment: While no number of positive tests could "prove" that it *is* valid, a single negative is adequate to prove that it is not, or that it is at least not advisable to use. While referencing the standard would be nice, proving that it doesn't work in at least one major compiler is sufficient evidence to say "it doesn't work" for the purposes of this discussion.

Answer (score 54):

[Conditional Compilation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Conditionals.html)

> You can use the defined operator in
>   the #if directive to use expressions
>   that evaluate to 0 or 1 within a
>   preprocessor line. This saves you from
>   using nested preprocessing directives.
>   The parentheses around the identifier
>   are optional. For example:
>
> ```
> #if defined (MAX) && ! defined (MIN)
> ```
>
> Without using the defined operator,
>   you would have to include the
>   following two directives to perform
>   the above example:
>
> ```
> #ifdef max 
> #ifndef min
> ```

Comment: While what you say is correct, this does not answer the question at all, he asked if the two are the same...they are not.

Comment: I think it says "they are not the same", you can see that it explains how to make an equivalent of #if defined(COND_A) && defined(COND_B) which is different from #ifdef COND_A && COND_B

Comment: Either way, this is a useful note.

Answer (score 4):

The following results are the same:

1.

```
#define A
#define B
#if(defined A && defined B)
printf("define test");
#endif
```

2.

```
#ifdef A
#ifdef B
printf("define test");
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: Can you please add some commentary to describe how this answers the question, its not clear from your answer.

Comment: This answer, while technically correct, doesn't accurately answer the question, and implies an incorrect usage. While the two blocks will do the same thing, nesting two ifs is not the same as using &&. Other conditions, such as an `#else`, could cause a problem. Only the first option actually means exactly what the asker asked for.

Answer (score 1):

For those that might be looking for example (UNIX/g++) that is a little different from the OP, this may help:

`

```
#if(defined A && defined B && defined C)
    const string foo = "xyz";
#else
#if(defined A && defined B)
    const string foo = "xy";
#else
#if(defined A && defined C)
    const string foo = "xz";
#else
#ifdef A
    const string foo = "x";
#endif
#endif
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: Why not just use #elif instead of #else #if and a billion #endif's at the end...?

Answer (score -3):

As of VS2015 none of the above works. The correct directive is:

```
#if (MAX && !MIN)
```

see more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx)

Comment: You have linked to C# documentation, not C++ one.