# Is a C++ preprocessor identical to a C preprocessor?

Tags: c++, c, standards, c-preprocessor

I am wondering how different the preprocessors for C++ and **C** are.

The reason for the question is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085392/what-is-the-value-of-an-undefined-constant-used-in-if-c) on a preprocessor-specific question where the paragraph of the standard that addresses the question has a different wording (and a different paragraph number) and also are difference concerning the `true` and `false` keywords in C++.

So, are there more differences or is this the only difference.

An extension of the question would be when is a source file emitted differently by a C++ preprocessor and a **C** preprocessor.

Comment: That "extension" question is really the same as the main question!

Comment: Yes, but the question was originally driven by that "extension".

Comment: Although similar to true and false, there are also the named operators: and, and_eq, bitand, bitor, compl, not, not_eq, or, or_eq,
xor and xor_eq.

Comment: Since C++11 not ending a translation unit w/ a newline is [no longer undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26127812/1708801)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The C++03 preprocessor is (at least intended to be) similar to the C preprocessor before C99. Although the wording and paragraph numbers are slightly different, the only technical differences I'm aware of between the two are that the C++ preprocessor handles digraphs (two-letter [alternative tokens](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative)) and universal character names, which are not present in C.

As of C99, the C preprocessor added some new capabilities (e.g., variadic macros) that do not exist in the current version of C++. I don't remember for sure, but don't believe that digraphs were added.

I believe C++0x will bring the two in line again (at least that's the intent). Again, the paragraph numbers and wording won't be identical, but I believe the intent is that they should work the same (other than retaining the differences mentioned above).

Comment: other than trigraphs, in C99 digraphs (but `%:` and the "quadrigraph" `%:%:`) are just tokens and not modified further in the preprocessing phase. They are then interpreted by the "real" compiler phases.

Comment: Also about C++03 vs C89, the C++ preprocessor has a special treatment of boolean literals.

Answer (score 6):

They are supposed to be the same: C++98 and C++03 should match C90, and C++0x should match C99.  There may be bugs in the wording, though.

Answer (score 6):

**Predefined macros** differ between the preprocessors, mostly for obvious language feature differences. E.g. compare:

- [C99 N1256 draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.10.8 "Predefined macro names"
- [C++11 N3337 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 16.8 "Predefined macro names"

In particular:

- C requires you not to define `__cplusplus`, C++ uses it to represent the version
- C uses `__STDC__` to represent the version, C++ says is implementation defined and uses `__cplusplus` instead
- C has `__STDC_IEC_559__` and `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__` to indicate floating point characteristics, C++ does not and seems replace that with the per type `std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559` constants
- C does not have the macros prefixed with `__STDCPP`: `_STDCPP_STRICT_POINTER_SAFETY__` and `__STDCPP_THREADS__`

As mentioned by DevSolar, C11 added many more defines which are not part of C++11.

Comment: Erm... you apparently forgot about C11... it's not only C++ that moved ahead. (Especially with regards to thread support and associated macros.)

Comment: @DevSolar thanks for the tip. Just to confirm: you mean that C11 added many more macros which are not in C++11 is that it? That's my impression on a quick look. Haven't looked into C++14, though, but there is stuff which won't be there for sure like `__STDC_NO_VLA__`

Comment: Well, *both* C11 and C++11 added threads, and the preprocessor macros necessary to handle them -- just different ones obviously. And I found it curious that you link C++11 documentation, but (outdated) C99 to compare. ;)

Comment: FYI: Syntax: C: `# non-directive`, C++: `# conditionally-supported-directive`.