# playing with Macros

Tags: c, macros

INSIDE "areaperi.h"

```
    #include <math.h>
        
    extern double peri;
    extern double area;
        
    #define AREA_C(x) (x*x* M_PI)
    #define PERI_C(x) (x*2*M_PI)
    
    #define PERI(length, depth, polygone){\
                if((polygone == "square")||(polygone == "rectangle"))\
                    peri = length * 2 + depth * 2;\
    }
    
    #define AREA(a,b,polygone){\
                if((polygone == "square")||(polygone == "rectangle"))\
                    area = a * b;\
                else if(polygone == "triangle")\
                    area = a * b / 2;\
    }
```

INSIDE "areaperi.c"

```
    #include "areaperi.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    
    int main(){
        double Carea = AREA_C(3);
        double Cperi = PERI_C(3);
        printf("area: %.2lf\n", Carea);
        printf("peri: %.2lf\n", Cperi);
        AREA(2,2,"square");
        printf("%.2lf\n", area);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Hi, trying to playing with Macros and storage class. But I am faced with an error. this code isn't meant to be efficient, it is just an exercise

**ERROR**

areaperi.h:14:28: warning: backslash-newline at end of file
#define AREA(a,b,polygone){\

C:\Users\elena\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyOjbOH.o:areaperi.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `area' C:\Users\elena\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyOjbOH.o:areaperi.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to` area'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: When asking questions about errors, then please always include the actual errors you get. Please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete error output into the question. Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As a ***guess***, where are the variables `peri` and `area` *defined*? You only declare them (as global variable), but you never define them anywhere?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude don't they get shared in the header file ?

Comment: When you use `extern` then it's an explicit declaration and not a potential definition. And using global variables like that is really bad. And it seems you might need to read a little more early chapters from your beginners text-book, as you seem to have forgotten how to compare strings (as well and you seem to need a remainder about the difference between a declaration and a definition).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thx indeed, but what do you propose

Comment: and they are defined inside the macros btw, but it seems to not work, how can I return the value form a macro?

Comment: For example `area = a * b;` inside the macro is a plain assignment, not a definition. A definition would be `int area;` in the global scope.

Comment: You have another problem with the macros: Try doing e.g. `AREA_C(1+2)` and the result might surprise you. For what your macros are doing, functions would be much better and less error-prone. With function you could eliminate the need for global variables, and just return the result.

Comment: ahhhh alright, ahah damn as you said, I unintentionally past that exact line on my text-book, thx really

Comment: Less bad alternative: `#define AREA(a, b, polygone) (!strcmp(polygone, "square") ? ((a) * (b)) : ((a) * (b) / 2)))`
Do not compare strings with `==`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**header file**

```
#include <math.h>

extern double peri;
extern double area;

#define AREA_C(x) (x*x* M_PI)
#define PERI_C(x) (x*2*M_PI)

#define PERI(length, depth, polygone){\
            if((polygone == "square")||(polygone == "rectangle"))\
                peri = length * 2 + depth * 2;\
}

#define AREA(a,b,poly){\
            if((poly == "square")||(poly == "rectangle"))\
                area = a * b;\
            else if(poly == "triangle")\
                area = a * b / 2;\
                puts("");\
}
```

**file.c**

```
#include "areaperi.h"
#include <stdio.h>

double area;
double peri;

int main(){
    double Carea = AREA_C(3);
    double Cperi = PERI_C(3);
    printf("area: %.2lf\n", Carea);
    printf("peri: %.2lf\n", Cperi);
    AREA(2,2,"square");
    printf("Area of the square: %.2lf\n", area);

    return 0;
}
```

**errors**

> after having DEFINED the variable I got rid of the main error, but there was still the `"24: warning: backslash-newline at end of file"`, with that one I just added `puts("");` and fix it.

If want to learn more about that error I find the answer on: [this stock overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708259/backslash-newline-at-end-of-file-warning)