# What are the differences between the C and C++ preprocessors?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, standards

Are there any differences in behaviour between the **C** and C++ preprocessors?

They are defined by different passages of standards text (section 6.10 of the [**C** standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and section 16 of the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)).

My motivation for asking this is that a [proposal for making the single quote a digit separator](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3781.pdf) that was recently accepted into C++14 extends the C++ preprocessor grammar to accomodate this change (specifically, it extends the definition of a *pp-number*), and I'm wondering whether this introduces an incompatibility between the **C** and C++ preprocessors, and if so, whether it's the first feature to do so.

Comment: In [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) both `g++` (actually `cc1plus`) and `gcc` (actually `cc1`) use the same `libcpp/` internal library for the preprocessing.

Comment: This answer gives some examples of differences that already exist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085533/is-a-c-preprocessor-identical-to-a-c-preprocessor

Comment: You could always look at variadic macros. C had them in C99. C++ had to wait until C++11.

Answer (score 10):

There are some differences between the C and C++ processors. Ignoring the differences in predefined macros and available system headers, some differences that come to mind in the current versions of C and of C++ are:

- `and` and friends are operators, not identifiers, in C++. This means `#define and &&` is valid in C, but not in C++, and means `#if 1 and 2` is valid in C++, but not in C (unless `and` is suitably defined as a macro).
- `false` and `true` are allowed in C++ `#if` expressions, but replaced by `0` (like all identifiers) in C. This means `#if true`/`C++`/`#else`/`C`/`#endif` expands to either `C++`, or `C`, depending on the language. Unlike `and` and friends, though, these are not operators, so may be redefined by `#define` in either language.
- `::`, `.*`, and `->*` are tokens in C++. As a result of that, the `##` operator can be used to form them in C++, but not in C.
- Raw string literals are available in C++, but not in C. As a result, given a macro `foo`, `R"x("foo")x"` expands the macro in C, but not in C++.
- Hexadecimal floating-point constants are available in C, but not in C++. As a result, given a macro `foo`, `0x1p+foo` expands the macro in C++, but not in C.

Comment: +1, but are you sure for the floating hex? PP numbers are not necessarily numbers for later phases, no? So floating hex might be valid PP numbers even in C++, but not recognized as numbers, later. Ah, and more important for the keyword/macro issue are probably `bool`, `false` and `true`.

Comment: @JensGustedt `+` is only allowed as part of a pp-number if it follows `e` or `E` (C++), or `e`, `E`, `p` or `P` (C). If it were unconditionally allowed, `1+2` would be invalid. (`0xE+0xF` is already invalid for the same reason, and that is already somewhat of a problem.)

Comment: @JensGustedt BTW, `false` and `true` are good points, but different from `and` because they aren't keywords. Will check for the exact details.

Comment: @hvd: `false` and `true` are keywords in C++ and not in C.

Comment: @KeithThompson Oops, I got my terminology wrong. You're right, `false` and `true` are keywords. `and` and friends are not, they're operators. Will edit.

Comment: In C, defining a keyword as a macro name has undefined behavior (N1570  6.4.1p2; it's a "shall" outside a constraint). So a conforming C or C++ preprocessor could just treat keywords as ordinary identifiers (I'm less sure about the C++ rules).

Comment: @hvd: Keywords and operators are not exclusive categories. `sizeof` is a keyword that's used as an operator. `and`, `or`, et al are listed separately from the keywords, but they're "reserved and shall not be used otherwise"; I'm not sure what distinction the Standard is making between these alternative representations and actual keywords.

Comment: @KeithThompson It says "The above tokens (case sensitive) are reserved (in translation phases 7 and 8) for use as keywords, and shall not be used otherwise.", which does allow use otherwise in other translation phases, unless I'm misreading.

Comment: @KeithThompson During preprocessing, there isn't anything that's both an operator and a keyword, is there? `sizeof` is only an operator after preprocessing.