# Is there any difference between the directive #include from C and the one from C++?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

No this question is not answered in the post ***What is the difference between `#include <filename>` and `#include “filename”`?***  This is a different question.
I am studying the differences between C and C++. I am doing this by comparing the most basic programs that you can make of each language:

In C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

In C++

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!!!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I know about headers and the compilation process. But i would like to know if there is any difference between the #include directive of C and C++. Like for example maybe the header content when is copied is copied in a different way.
I think this question is very straightforward, you can answer it by saying "No" or "yes, here are the differences: 1), 2)".

Comment: I think this question has got to have plenty of duplicates.

Comment: I think header content isn't "copied" by either language.

Comment: `#include` is a CPP (**C** /C++ **P** re **P** rocessor) directive, and not a C or C++ command.

Comment: One could argue that the C program presented is an even more basic C++ program than is the presented C++ analog.

Comment: I don't understand the many downvotes, that's a legit question for a beginners doubts if `#include` works the same way for c and c++. So find a dupe or shut up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Comment: @EvanCarslake No, not really. I've been looking up that just before, but it doesn't answer if there are really differences for c or c++.

Comment: @callyalater  In C, `#include` is called a _preprocessing directive_ and also call a _directive_.  The "CPP (C /C++ P re P rocessor)" you mention is not in the C spec, but the functionality of `#include` is.  C does not define " C command".

Comment: Thank you guys! Don't think I just post the question without doing some research... i didn't find the answer in any other post. Thank you alot πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: "I am studying the differences between C and C++." While a noble undertaking, I question the purpose of it. It's not a good way to learn either - C++ is really a completely different language. It's best studied in isolation from C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there are at least two differences. In C++ (WG21 N4567 [cpp.include]/5):

> The implementation shall provide unique mappings for sequences
>   consisting of one or more *nondigit*s or *digit*s (2.10) followed by a
>   period (`.`) and a single *nondigit*. The first character shall not be
>   a *digit*. The implementation may ignore distinctions of alphabetical
>   case.

In C (WG14 N1570 6.10.2/5, emphasis mine):

> The implementation shall provide unique mappings for sequences
>   consisting of one or more nondigits or digits (6.4.2.1) followed by a
>   period (`.`) and a single nondigit. The first character shall not be a
>   digit. The implementation may ignore distinctions of alphabetical case
>   and **restrict the mapping to eight significant characters before the
>   period**.

A conforming C implementation can map "`foobarbaz.h`" and "`foobarbat.h`" to the same source file. A conforming C++ implementation cannot.

---

Additionally, in C (N1570 6.4.7):

> If the characters `'`, `\`, `"`, `//`, or `/*` occur in the sequence
>   between the `<` and `>` delimiters, **the behavior is undefined**.
>   Similarly, if the characters `'`, `\`, `//`, or `/*` occur in the
>   sequence between the `"` delimiters, **the behavior is undefined**.

while in C++ (N4567 [lex.header]/2):

> The appearance of either of the characters `'` or `\` or of either of
>   the character sequences `/*` or `//` in a *q-char-sequence* or an
>   *h-char-sequence* is **conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics**, as is the appearance of the
>   character `"` in an *h-char-sequence*.

"conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics" means that

- if the implementation doesn't support it, it must issue a diagnostic;
- if the implementation does support it, its interpretation of this construct must be documented.

while "undefined behavior" means that the implementation can do whatever it wants.

Comment: Thank you for your answer T.C.

Comment: TL;DR: In practice, there are no differences unless you have some really broken source code.

Answer (score 9):

> Like for example maybe the header content when is copied is copied in a different way.

The `#include` preprocessor directive is handled by the CPP preprocessor, that is (mostly) the same for C and C++ compilation. Diverging C and C++ standards might introduce [subtle differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085533/is-a-c-preprocessor-identical-to-a-c-preprocessor), but none of these affects how the `#include` directive should be handled regarding how the file's content is replaced into the translation unit (besides how the header file names are expanded and matched, see [@T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36292219/1413395)).

The CPP does merely text replacement and just expands what's seen from the included file into the translation unit, be it C or C++ code.

> I think this question is very straightforward, you can answer it by saying "No" or "yes, here are the differences: 1), 2)".

No, there's no differences for the `#include` directive is working regarding the text replacement.

---

<sub>Well, from the results the C compiler might not be able to compile code expanded from C++ header files correctly, and sometimes vice versa.</sub>

Comment: It's been mentioned the other day that C++ preprocessor is different from C preprocessor, but I did not see any specific difference.

Comment: @SergeyA _"It's been mentioned the other day ..."_ Do you have a specific link for this mentioning? I'm just curious what the difference should actually be.

Comment: I thought there was a difference in the tolerance of having a `#if`  `#endif` spread across 2 different files or some other similar questionable programming practice - IDK.  Yet for practical concerns, I know of no difference,.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I found the links for the differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085533/is-a-c-preprocessor-identical-to-a-c-preprocessor and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515608/what-are-the-differences-between-the-c-and-c-preprocessors

Comment: @SergeyA THX a lot. Though at least there aren't any differences how the `#include` directive is handled, right?

Comment: Certainly doesn't seem so. But, *the CPP preprocessor, that is the same for C and C++ compilation* is a general statement :)

Comment: @SergeyA I've integrated that into my answer.

Comment: "none of these affects how the `#include` directive should be handled" At least one does.

Comment: @T.C. You mean the _"that the C++ preprocessor handles digraphs and universal character names, which are not present in C"_ part?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, right, but now TC provided an ultimate anser. Sorry, my upvote goes to the Ultimate Answer On Difference and all.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, there are typically more directories being searched. This is technically not a difference in the *directive*, though.

For example, on my system:

```
 % gcc -E -v -x c - <<< '' 2>&1 | sed -n '/cc1/,/End of search list/p'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1 -E -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

```
% gcc -E -v -x c++ - <<< '' 2>&1 | sed -n '/cc1/,/End of search list/p'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus -E -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/5
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5
 /usr/include/c++/5/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

Additionally, there are differences between the preprocessors that do *not* involve `#include`:

- named operators are builtin in C++. In C, you must `#include <iso646.h>`
- boolean keywords are builtin in C++. In C, you must `#include <stdbool.h>`
- Since C++14, `'` is available as a digit separators. (It is universally agreed that this was a bad idea, but the committee wouldn't accept anything else).