# Why is #define not properly defined in child classes?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have a define in the base classes header file. Using the define in a derived class is not possible:

Plugin.h

```
#ifndef PLUGIN_H
#define PLUGIN_H

#include "../config.h"

#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_PLUGIN(...) ets_printf( __VA_ARGS__ )
#else
#define DEBUG_PLUGIN(...)
#endif


class Plugin {
public:
  Plugin();
  ...
```

SimplePlugin.h

```
#ifndef SIMPLE_PLUGIN_H
#define SIMPLE_PLUGIN_H

#include "Plugin.h"

class SimplePlugin : public Plugin {
public:
  SimplePlugin();
  ...
```

SimplePlugin.cpp

```
#include "SimplePlugin.h"

SimplePlugin::SimplePlugin() : _devices() {
  DEBUG_PLUGIN("[SimplePlugin]\n");     // <-- not printed
}
```

`config.h` has `DEBUG` defined. Could you highlight the preprocessor magic?

**UPDATE**

The comments got me on the right track. Macro expansion does of course not depend on class hierarchy, in fact not on the compiler at all but on the preprocessor. The macro is defined, expanded by preprocessor an executes, otherwise we would see compile errors.

It finally turned out that the Arduino/esp8266 `ets_printf` function needs additional hardware configuration or it will only work unreliably. That unreliable behaviour made it look like as if it was only called depending on location in the file/class hierarchy.

Comment: Are you sure that the ets_printf function works properly?

Comment: Did you actually create an instance of SimplePlugin?

Comment: Macro's behavior has nothing to do with classes and derivation. However, your header file inclusion structure looks fine, meaning that most likely the macro works and works exactly as it should. If something is "not printed" in your case, preprocessor and the macro are not to blame for that.

Comment: When do you expect that to get printed? And what is `ets_printf`? That's not a standard function. Where is it supposed to print? Are you sure?

Comment: If a amacro weren't defined, you'd get compilation error, not missing output from running executable.

Comment: The issue is likely somewhere in `config.h`, since the problem seems to be that `DEBUG` isn't defined by the time the compiler gets to `DEBUG_PLUGIN`'s definition in `Plugin.h`.  I tested it in TutorialsPoint's online compiler with the same file setup as your question, and it worked.  (See http://goo.gl/a8MtrF , although you may need to `g++ main.cpp SimplePlugin.cpp` before you can run `a.out`.)

Comment: Thanks @JustinTime for the online compiler, excellent.

Comment: You're welcome.  Hope you get it working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvious possible explanations would be

- `ets_printf()` - which is non-standard, and you have not described - does not work as you believe.   For example, it could itself be a macro that is defined to do nothing if `DEBUG` is defined.
- `DEBUG` is not actually defined in your `config.h`.  A typo somewhere could easily mean some other macro is being defined, rather than the one you believe.
- The header might actually be defining `DEBUG` but the preprocessor subsequently encounters an `#undef DEBUG`.   That may be in the same header, a different header, or even in your including source file.

The problem is unlikely to have anything to do with definitions of classes or constructor.   The preprocessor does not follow scoping rules.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should read much more about the [C/C++ preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) (both C & C++ share the *same* preprocessor, with [some differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5085588/841108) in predefined macros). It is operating textually only. It has no notion of types (e.g. `class`), or of scope.

You could get the preprocessed form of `SimplePlugin.cpp`  using a command line like:

```
g++ -C -E SimplePlugin.cpp > SimplePlugin.ii
```

<sup>(you could have to add some additional `-D`*symbol* and `-I`*directory* before the `-C`, exactly as in your compilation command)</sup>

Then, look into the generated `SimplePlugin.ii` file (the preprocessed form from `SimplePlugin.cpp`...) with your editor or pager.

You might even remove the line information (emitted by the preprocessor in lines starting with `#`) with

```
    g++ -C -E SimplePlugin.cpp | grep -v '^#' > SimplePlugin.nolines.ii
```

and then you could run `g++ -c -Wall SimplePlugin.nolines.ii`, the diagnostics would refer to the preprocessed file `SimplePlugin.nolines.ii`, not the original unpreprocessed `SimplePlugin.cpp`

Read also the documentation of [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/)

<sup>(I am guessing you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/); please adapt my answer to your compiler suite; I am even guessing that your bug might be unrelated to preprocessing)</sup>

Comment: C and C++ preprocessors have much in common but are not actually identical.  There is plenty of discussion about,  for example  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085533/is-a-c-preprocessor-identical-to-a-c-preprocessor

Comment: @Peter: Thanks, improved my answer.

Comment: Good answer but not root cause.