# Which Cross Platform Preprocessor Defines? (__WIN32__ or __WIN32 or WIN32 )?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I often see `__WIN32`, `WIN32` or `__WIN32__`. I assume that this depends on the used preprocessor (either one from visual studio, or gcc etc).

Do I now have to check first for os and then for the used compiler? We are using here G++ 4.4.x, Visual Studio 2008 and Xcode (which I assume is a gcc again) and ATM we are using just `__WIN32__`, `__APPLE__` and `__LINUX__`.

Comment: `_WIN32` is systematic, more offen that other spellings. See https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/ . The good practice is to test what is relevant in each situation (OS, archi, compiler...) and not test one for the other. And also not redefine your own.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends what you are trying to do. You can check the compiler if your program wants to make use of some specific functions (from the gcc toolchain for example). You can check for operating system ( `_WINDOWS`, `__unix__` ) if you want to use some OS specific functions (regardless of compiler - for example `CreateProcess` on Windows and `fork` on unix).

[Macros for Visual C](https://web.archive.org/web/20100422132954/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.80).aspx)

[Macros for gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html)

You must check the documentation of each compiler in order to be able to detect the differences when compiling. I remember that the gnu toolchain(gcc) has some functions in the C library ([libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)) that are not on other toolchains (like Visual C for example). This way if you want to use those functions out of commodity then you must detect that you are using GCC, so the code you must use would be the following:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
// do my gcc specific stuff
#else
// ... handle this for other compilers
#endif
```

Answer (score 65):

This article answers your question:

- [*C/C++ tip: How to detect the operating system type using compiler predefined macros*](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system) (plus [archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140625123925/http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system) in case it vanishes).

The article is quite long, and includes tables that are hard to reproduce, but here's the essence:

You can detect Unix-style OS with:

```
#if !defined(_WIN32) && (defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix) || (defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)))
    /* UNIX-style OS. ------------------------------------------- */

#endif
```

Once you know it's Unix, you can find if it's POSIX and the POSIX version with:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#if defined(_POSIX_VERSION)
    /* POSIX compliant */
#endif
```

You can check for BSD-derived systems with:

```
#if defined(__unix__) || (defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__))
#include <sys/param.h>
#if defined(BSD)
    /* BSD (DragonFly BSD, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD). ----------- */

#endif
#endif
```

and Linux with:

```
#if defined(__linux__)
    /* Linux  */
#endif
```

and Apple's operating systems with

```
#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
    /* Apple OSX and iOS (Darwin) */
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR == 1
    /* iOS in Xcode simulator */
#elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE == 1
    /* iOS on iPhone, iPad, etc. */    
#elif TARGET_OS_MAC == 1
    /* OS X */
#endif
#endif
```

Windows with Cygwin

```
#if defined(__CYGWIN__) && !defined(_WIN32)
    /* Cygwin POSIX under Microsoft Windows. */
#endif
```

And non-POSIX Windows with:

```
#if defined(_WIN64)
    /* Microsoft Windows (64-bit) */
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    /* Microsoft Windows (32-bit) */
#endif
```

The full article lists the following symbols, and shows which systems define them and when: `_AIX`, `__APPLE__`, `__CYGWIN32__`, `__CYGWIN__`, `__DragonFly__`, `__FreeBSD__`, `__gnu_linux`, `hpux`, `__hpux`, `linux`, `__linux`, `__linux__`, `__MACH__`, `__MINGW32__`, `__MINGW64__`, `__NetBSD__`, `__OpenBSD__`, `_POSIX_IPV6`, `_POSIX_MAPPED_FILES`, `_POSIX_SEMAPHORES`, `_POSIX_THREADS`, `_POSIX_VERSION`, `sun`, `__sun`, `__SunOS`, `__sun__`, `__SVR4`, `__svr4__`, `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR`, `TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED`, `TARGET_OS_IPHONE`, `TARGET_OS_MAC`, `UNIX`, `unix`, `__unix`, `__unix__`, `WIN32`, `_WIN32`, `__WIN32`, `__WIN32__`, `WIN64`, `_WIN64`, `__WIN64`, `__WIN64__`, `WINNT`, `__WINNT`, `__WINNT__`.

A [related article](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/10/c_c_tip_how_detect_compiler_name_and_version_using_compiler_predefined_macros) ([archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140625123200/http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/10/c_c_tip_how_detect_compiler_name_and_version_using_compiler_predefined_macros)) covers detecting compilers and compiler versions. It lists the following symbols: `__clang__`, `__GNUC__`, `__GNUG__`, `__HP_aCC`, `__HP_cc`, `__IBMCPP__`, `__IBMC__`, `__ICC`, `__INTEL_COMPILER`, `_MSC_VER`, `__PGI`, `__SUNPRO_C`, `__SUNPRO_CC` for detecting compilers, and `__clang_major__`, `__clang_minor__`, `__clang_patchlevel__`, `__clang_version__`, `__GNUC_MINOR__`, `__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__`, `__GNUC__`, `__GNUG__`, `__HP_aCC`, `__HP_cc`, `__IBMCPP__`, `__IBMC__`, `__ICC`, `__INTEL_COMPILER`, `__INTEL_COMPILER_BUILD_DATE`, `_MSC_BUILD`, `_MSC_FULL_VER`, `_MSC_VER`, `__PGIC_MINOR__`, `__PGIC_PATCHLEVEL__`, `__PGIC__`, `__SUNPRO_C`, `__SUNPRO_CC`, `__VERSION__`, `__xlC_ver__`, `__xlC__`, `__xlc__` for detecting compiler versions.

Comment: What an awesome list! I wish such information came "built" in with the documentation for LLVM/Clang, GCC, and friends... and not buried here on SO (where, ultimately, Google _will_ find it, but... you know what I mean)

Answer (score 4):

Don't see why you have to. You might have to remember to specify the definition manually on your compiler's commandline, but that's all. For the record, Visual Studio's definition is [`_WIN32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.80).aspx) (with one underscore) rather than `__WIN32`. If it's not defined then it's not defined, and it won't matter.

Comment: So I could write the `#ifdef __WIN32__` only once and not `#ifdef WIN32 || __WIN32 || __WIN32__`

Comment: @brubelsabs: Yes, but you'd have to remember to put in the preprocessor definition yourself on the commandline if you decided to use another compiler.

Comment: AFAIK `_WIN32` is defined for all (modern) Windows compilers (excluding WinCE of course). No need to define it yourself...

Comment: @math: Your `#ifdef`-expression is wrong. It should be `#if defined(WIN32) || defined(__WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__)`. See [C Preprocessor directives and boolean operators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/965700/1889329) for reference.

Comment: @IInspectable: Or perhaps `#if WIN32 || _WIN32 || __WIN32__`.  Undefined names are treated as zero.  The question is what should be done in case of `#define _WIN32 0`.

Comment: @Ben: You have already answered, why your proposed `#if`-expression is inappropriate. If you want to check whether a preprocessor symbol is defined, it is best to check whether a preprocessor symbol is defined.

Comment: @IInspectable: But why do you think it is more appropriate to treat `#define _WIN32 0` the same as `#define _WIN32 1`, rather than `#undef _WIN32` ?

Comment: @Ben: Because that is how it is specified and documented. [Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx): *"**_WIN32** Defined for applications for Win32 and Win64."*

Answer (score 4):

I've rebuild my answer... Damn, editing berserk :P:

You don't need to use partical one. And probably for MacOSX, Linux and other Unix-likes you don't need to use any at all.

Most popular one is (as far as Google tells the truth) is `_WIN32`.

You **never** define it "by hand" in your source code. It is defined in one of these ways:
as a commandline preprocessor/compiler flag (like `g++ -D _WIN32`)
or it is predefined by compiler itself (most of Windows compilers predefine `_WIN32`, and sometimes other like `WIN32` or `_WIN32_` too. -- Then you don't need to worry about defining it at all, compiler does the whole work.

---

And my old answer:

You don't 'have to' anything. It's just for multi-platform compatibility. Often version of code for all Unix-likes (including Linux, MacOSX, BSD, Solaris...) and other POSIX platform will be completely the same and there must be some changes for Windows. So people write their code generally for Unix-likes and put some Windows-only (eg. DirectX instructions, Windows-like file paths...) parts between `#ifdef _WIN32` and `#endif`.

If you have some parts eg. X-Window-system only, or MacOS-only, you do similar with something like `#ifdef X_WINDOW` or `#ifdef MACOS`. Then, you need set a proper preprocessor definition while compiling (with gcc using -D flag, like eg. `gcc -D _WIN32`).

If you don't write any platform-dependent code, then you don't need to care for such a `#ifdef, #else, #endif` blocks. And most of Windows compilers/preprocessors AFAIK have predefined some symbols like `_WIN32` (most popular, as far as google tells the truth), `WIN32`, `_WIN32_`, etc. So compiling it on Windows most probably you don't need to make anything else than just compiling.

Comment: Probably my question is very unclear: I don't want to define WIN32 but to use it with `#ifdef`. And I wondered why there are so many variants and if there is one which should work with most of the compiliers.

Comment: As I said, people just use what they like, there is no standard. Anyway, you can define it when compiling yourself in commandline (and also in IDE options, etc.), so using "unsupported" WIN32__ instead of "good" _WIN32 isn't a problem.

And, as I said, most compilers support _WIN32 and some support many others (mingw support WIN32 _WIN32 WIN32 __WIN32 MINGW32 WINNT WINNT __WINNT).

See this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive

Answer (score 0):

Sigh - don't rely on compiler anything - specify which platform you are building for in your Makefile.   Simply put, anything beginning with _ is implementation dependent and not portable.

I tried your method once upon a time, on a very large project, and in between bouncing around between Sun-C++ and GCC we just decided to go with Makefile control rather than trying to deduce what the compilers were going to do.

Comment: You can create wrappers for different behaviors and use those wrappers. This way you deal with platform/compiler differences in just a few source files, which is (in my opinion) better that dealing with makefiles for each platform.

Comment: You have a valid point.  However, I can't conceive of a situation where you're supporting multiple platforms and aren't using Makefiles of some sort (gmake/cmake/qmake) anyway.  Windows library definitions to link.exe are not the same as gcc -L -l.  Nor are compiler optimization settings.  I'd much rather deal with my platform flags in one Makefile (or a few by inclusion) than have to remember to include platform_magic.h in every header/source file. 
Boost does it your way - in boost/system/config.hpp it determines what platform it's running on.  We'll just have to agree to disagree.  :-D