# Is there a list of preprocessor defines for various operating systems (and versions)?

Tags: c++, operating-system, c-preprocessor

e.g. a mapping for

Mac OS 10.6.3 aka Snow Leopard => `__APPLE__ && __LP64__`?

Windows 7, Windows XP => `__WIN32__`

Linux => `__LINUX__`

Comment: Duplicate of [Which Cross Platform Preprocessor Defines? (`__WIN32__` or `__WIN32` or `WIN32`)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989810/which-cross-platform-preprocessor-defines-win32-or-win32-or-win32) (You just asked this question; why are you asking it a second time?  If you want macros for multiple platforms, you should modify your original question to clarify it)

Comment: No, first question targets on which define in terms of underscores to choose but this amis at what options do I have in gerneral when targeting a certain platform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go: http://predef.sourceforge.net/