# Specify the platform using #ifdefs

Tags: c++, c

To handle platform specific code between Mac and Windows, **WIN32** and **APPLE** are the terms to use, right?

So, thw code would look like this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    // Windows code
#endif
#ifdef __APPLE__
    // Mac code
#endif
```

What about Linux ?

How can i do that for all three? right

Comment: how about `#ifdef __LINUX__`? (Btw `#ifdef _WIN32` won't detect 64-bit Windows!)

Comment: _WIN32 works fine on 64-bit projects.  It only says "32" because there used to be a "16".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a list of preprocessor defines for various operating systems (and versions)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990172/is-there-a-list-of-preprocessor-defines-for-various-operating-systems-and-versi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's similar:

```
#ifdef __linux__
    // Linux code
#endif
```

Since you are going to have either one of these three defined at a time, this should be ok for all three.

[List of defines.](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/predef/index.php?title=Operating_Systems#linux)

Comment: SHouldn't it be __LINUX__ and not __linux__? or that dont matter, btw you didn't tell me if i was doint it right with the others

Comment: lowercase. Different OSes have different names. __linux__ for liux. I updated the answer with a link for others too.