# GCC preprocessor

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running the GCC preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916979)

Is there a [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) option to make the GCC preprocessor generate **C** source code but filter out irrelevant source code?

For example, a **C** file has `#define switch` to define for many different platforms. I'm only intersted in one platform, so I want the **C** preprocessor to filter out unrelated code. Does GCC support this?

Comment: Exact duplicate (looks like same user, earlier today): [gcc preprocessor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916979/gcc-preprocessor)

Comment: @Paul Is indeed the same user; the original version of this question before Michael cleaned it up was word-for-word identical, including the *Richard Luo* sig.

Answer (score 44):

Use `gcc` [`-E`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-E) to only run the preprocessor part, e.g., given a file, *in.c*,

```
#if 0
0;
#endif

#if 1
1;
#endif
```

running

```
gcc -E in.c -o in.i
```

yields a file, *in.i*:

```
# 1 "in.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "in.cpp"





1;
```

I.e., the parts behind the `#if 0` got removed. If you would have `#include`'d files, they would have been pasted too though, so I am not sure how much help this is.

Comment: thanks for answer. maybe my question is not clear enough. but honk answered my question.

Comment: What do the `# 1` lines mean?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you actually want [unifdef](http://freshmeat.net/projects/unifdef/), not the GCC preprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - almost certainly your compiler provides certain default definitions in the environment that you can use to turn code on and off for different systems.  `__GNUC__` is a good one for GCC.  For example:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define SOME_VALUE 12
#else
#define SOME_VALUE 14
#endif
```

If you compile that block with GCC, `SOME_VALUE` will be `12`, and if you compile with MSVC, for example, `SOME_VALUE` will be 14.  A list of platform specific definitions is available at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989810/which-cross-platform-preprocessor-defines-win32-or-win32-or-win32).

Answer (score -1):

You probably can use:

```
gcc -CC -P -Uswitch -undef -nostdinc -fdirectives-only -dDI -E
```

With `switch` the `#define` you know will be undefined.