# Define Macro for Project Text Files

Tags: c++, macros

I have a c++ project, is it possible to define a macro in the project that affects the text files in the project as well. So to have in the c++ something like 
"#define ANIMAL dog"

Text File:
Good ANIMAL

c++ reads in the text file as:
Good dog

Since the text files wouldn't be compiled I wouldn't think there'd be a way, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't have the slightest clue what you're asking about. You seem to confuse a lot of things.

Comment: No using macros in your `c++` code will not substitute text in your data files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define macros are read by the preprocessor (part of the compiler). But your text files aren't typically processed by the preprocessor.

However, this answer might be helpful to you:

[Stack Overflow Question on Running Preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473036/run-gcc-preprocessor-non-c-files)