# GCC requiring underscore in #define's?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I am testing two versions of the same code (with GCC version 4.9.2 on Linux, no parameters).

Both have a `#define` directive, followed by an `#ifdef`/`#endif` pair further down.

Now, it turns out that the combination works properly only if the label after the initial `#define` starts with an underscore. Without the underscore, it works.... in a very weird way, only every third time.

In other words, this works

```
#define _whatever
```

while this doesn't:

```
#define whatever
```

Even though I know how to make the directive work, just curious - does that behavior follow any standard?

**Edit**:
Following requests below, here's two absolutely real examples.
This one prints the line "Preprocessor works":

```
#define _whatever
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
#ifdef _whatever
printf("Preprocessor works \n");
#endif
}
```

... and this one doesn't output anything:

```
#define whatever
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
#ifdef whatever
printf("Preprocessor works \n");
#endif
}
```

Yes, I am even using the word "whatever" literally - I don't think, it is defined anywhere else. But again, it's the underscore that makes the label work.

Comment: You don't show what is the part of the code that works or stops working.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Ok, real examples:

Comment: Both of those examples work just fine.

Comment: @Lundin: As they should. Just not in my very specific case....

Comment: ...which is what?

Comment: @Lundin: the version of gcc I indicated. I'm really at a loss as to what further info to add. I'm using command line; there's only one file main.c in the folder. No parameters. I first put gcc *.c, and then run the output as ./a.out

Comment: I tested it in gcc 4.9.1. I find it highly unlikely that this is some compiler bug. Is this code really a copy/paste of the real code?

Comment: I agree with you wrt compiler bugs. Just tested the literal whatever example, and it started working. But not in my original code, where I just triple-checked the labels. Guess, I need a bit more time for this - will be back.

Comment: Adding `#ifndef whatever #error FAIL #endif` (with linebreaks of course) directly after `#define whatever` should work. Start from there, and start moving this test down the file until you find exact location where it starts failing.

Comment: @user694733: Noted - thanks.

Comment: @vanhemt Also, examine the *entire*  preprocessed output from gcc.  `gcc -E input.c -o input.i`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917316/gcc-preprocessor

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no requirement, in any known version of gcc, that preprocessor macros begin with an underscore.

As a general rule, preprocessor macros that begin with various combinations of underscores are reserved to the implementation, and users are advised to ignore them.  So `#define whatever` and `#ifdef whatever` absolutely must work.

I agree that this is a baffling and frustrating problem.  There's something strange going on, but whatever the explanation is, it's not that gcc is requiring leading underscores.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so the answer is - my sloppy command of the tools.

**Specifically:**

(1) I was using a header file to add/remove the #define directive

(2) I have (mindlessly) compiled the header by using "gcc *" in place of "gcc *.c"

(3) The occasional presence of the compiled *.h.gch file explains the results.

So, what seemed like erratic behavior was actually me (mindlessly) removing the *.h.gch from time to time.

Thanks everyone - I have learned a lot from all the replies.