# C Pre-processor directives, Is this correct syntax? #Ifdef foo || bar

Tags: c, syntax

I have a pre-processor directive as such,

```
//#define SPEC_CONTROL  // Is not defined, but can be if need be
#define SPEC_A_CONTROL  // Is defined

#ifdef SPEC_CONTROL || SPEC_A_CONTROL
    ; // do something
#else
    ; // do something else
#endif
```

Is it correct syntax to use the `||` in the manner I did?

Comment: Tried and no error, but the code is not working as I presumed it would. I just needed a sanity check.

Comment: [This link](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/cint/ifdef.html) will be helpful.

Comment: By this kind of problems you can always use #error 0, #error 1, or #warning inside if and else to see what exactly precompiler includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can assure yout that at least

```
#if defined(SPEC_CONTROL) || defined(SPEC_A_CONTROL)
```

works on Windows and several UNIX platforms. Im not sure about

```
#ifdef SPEC_CONTROL || SPEC_A_CONTROL
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Now the compiler is calling out all the others as errors, but it was oddly ok when they were all as I had them? Welp, now I can get moving again thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean logic in a C preprocessor directive by using the `if defined` directive.

See this post for more information:
[C Preprocessor testing definedness of multiple macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965700/c-preprocessor-directives-and-boolean-operators)